# Access ArgoCD server

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am following the `Installation Instructions` from https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/getting_started/#3-access-the-argo-cd-api-server
and even though the service type has been changes to `LoadBalancer` I cannot manage to login.

The information I have is:

```
$ oc describe svc argocd-server
Name:                     argocd-server
Namespace:                argocd
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=server
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server
                          app.kubernetes.io/part-of=argocd
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       172.30.70.178
LoadBalancer Ingress:     a553569222264478ab2xx1f60d88848a-642416295.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30942/TCP
Endpoints:                10.128.3.91:8080
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 https  30734/TCP
Endpoints:                10.128.3.91:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

If I do:

```
$ oc login https://a553569222264478ab2xx1f60d88848a-642416295.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
The server is using a certificate that does not match its hostname: x509: certificate is valid for localhost, argocd-server, argocd-server.argocd, argocd-server.argocd.svc, argocd-server.argocd.svc.cluster.local, not a553569222264478ab2xx1f60d88848a-642416295.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
You can bypass the certificate check, but any data you send to the server could be intercepted by others.
Use insecure connections? (y/n): y

error: Seems you passed an HTML page (console?) instead of server URL.
Verify provided address and try again.
```

Answer (score 7):

I managed to successfully login argocd-server by the following

```
kubectl patch svc argocd-server -n argocd -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'

argoPass=$(kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret \
    -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d)

argocd login --insecure --grpc-web k3s_master:32761 --username admin \
    --password $argoPass
```

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to expose an ArgoCD server via ingress, you can disable the TLS by  patching the argocd-server deployment:

no-tls.yaml

---

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: argocd-server
        command: 
          - argocd-server
          - --insecure
```

```
kubectl patch deployment -n argocd argocd-server --patch-file no-tls.yaml
```

Comment: this does not appear to work any longer. vanilla argocd deployment `kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/core-install.yaml` does not have a `deployment/argocd-server`. The result of `kubectl patch deployment -n argocd argocd-server --patch-file no-tls.yaml` is
`Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "argocd-server" not found`

Comment: It still works just fine: `deployment.apps/argocd-server patched`. @user3753342 - it seems your cluster is missing that argocd/argocd-server deployment resource.

Comment: This does not work any longer. The patch is accepted, but the argocd-server goes into CrashLoopBackOff. The pod logs show the following `Error: unknown command "/usr/local/bin/argocd-server" for "argocd-server"
Run 'argocd-server --help' for usage.
`

Comment: As of now, you need to add an extra key to the `argocd-cmd-params-cm` config-map.

The value should be: `server.insecure: "true"`

Answer (score 3):

check your svc on argocd

```
kubectl get svc -n argocd
```

[image]

If the type is NodePort then that is fine, if not then here is the conversion method:

```
kubectl patch svc argocd-server -n argocd -p '{"spec": {"type": "NodePort"}}'
```

And then to access the ArgoCD server to browser, put the IP address of the VM plus the port that NodePort will provide as in the picture
Once run, your ArgoCD cluster will be available at **`https://<hosted-node-ip>:<NodePort>`**

Answer (score 2):

By default, argocd server run with  self signed tls enabled. Your are trying to access the argocd server with different url with tls enabled. The API server should be run with TLS disabled. Edit the argocd-server deployment to add the --insecure flag to the argocd-server command.

```
      containers:
      - command:
        - argocd-server
        - --staticassets
        - /shared/app
        - --insecure
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to login argocd-server by using below command

argocd login --insecure --grpc-web  test-server.companydomain.com --grpc-web-root-path  /argocd

Username: admin

Password:

'admin:login' logged in successfully

I am using traefik as ingress controller. My server can be accessed on browser https://test-server.companydomain.com/argocd

Comment: I'm using Traefik in EKS. AWS NLB is just a pass-through but it throws "Internal server error". 
argocli throws error as well 

`FATA[0004] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = POST https://argocd-dashboard.xxx.com:443/argocd/session.SessionService/Create failed with status code 500`

My Traefik config - Intried inclusing certResolver as Default and my clusterissuer name, still the same result.

Comment: Followed per the documentaiton:
`apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
..
  tls:
    certResolver: traefik-letsencrypt-1  # Default or I removed this line as well, still 500 Internal error.
    secretName: argocd-cert # same content as in traefik-cert
    domains:
      - main: argocd-dashboard.xxxx.com
`